# enter multiple items(image, text, image, text) in arrayadapter, custom listview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

i want to create custom listview, shown in image, as i am unable to add data i.e., image, text, image, text
now can anyone can guide me to enter data in listview?
i had done with one text and one image, now i want these two texts nd two images.

```
android.widget.ListView viewall=(android.widget.ListView)findViewById(R.id.viewall);

        final ArrayList<ViewReview> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        ViewReview r1=new ViewReview();
        ViewReview r2=new ViewReview();

        ViewReview adapter=new ViewReview(this,arrayList);
        viewall.setAdapter(adapter);


//--------------Adapter class
package com.example.ali_raza.cook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Ali_Raza on 15-06-2017.
 */

public class ViewReview extends ArrayAdapter<Reviewlist> {
public ViewReview(Context context, ArrayList arraylist,Context c){
        super(context,0,arraylist);

        }



    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        View viewall=view;
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        if(view==null){
        viewall=inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviewcustom,parent,false);

        }
        Reviewlist r=getItem(position);
        ImageView image1=(ImageView)viewall.findViewById(R.id.userimage);
        TextView text1=(TextView)viewall.findViewById(R.id.nameuser);
        ImageView image2=(ImageView)viewall.findViewById(R.id.star);
        TextView text2=(TextView)viewall.findViewById(R.id.paragraph);

        image1.setImageResource(r.getRateimage());
        text1.setText(r.getNameuser());
        image2.setImageResource(r.getStar());
        text2.setText(r.getRev());


        return viewall;
        }

        }
[enter image description here][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBM6q.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean class which will have all your data.

Then pass the array list of your custom bean class `ArrayList<YourBean>` to the adapter.

Then create a custom adapter by extending built in `BaseAdapter` class.

Comment: Take a look into this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/